# Matching tenses of sentences

Tags: tenses, syntactic-analysis

```
I'm writing to enquire whether there is a need for ...  
Wishing to be a part of your team thought the best way to go about it
was to ask you directly.

My background is mostly with ... but my interests lie with ...
```

My question is about the second and third sentences - I don't know how, or if at all, they can be rewritten to match the tense of the first one.

Comment: @TimLymington - Apologies. Sometimes the things that are under your nose are hardest to see.

Answer (score 2):

The tenses are fine: You *are writing* now because you *thought* something in the past. It would be grammatical to say *I think the best way...* but this is not very idiomatic, and sounds rather pushy.

There are other problems with your prose, though. The first sentence is missing a subject. At a minimum, you need to insert a comma and *I* before *thought*, but it would be better to split up the sentence, perhaps "I would like to be a part of your team; I thought the best way was to ask directly" (assuming the first lacuna is the name or description of a job).

And the prepositions in your second paragraph depend on what exactly fills the blanks.  Your background may be *with IBM*, *in electronics* or possibly *at Harvard*; too general a question misses out the context needed to give a good answer.

Comment: Tim, thank you for a very clear answer. You're right about the second part - I intentionally omitted some parts fearing this might be closed as too localised. If you'll permit, in the whole they go "I'm writing to enquire whether there is a need for naval architects at ... Wishing to be a part of your team, thought the best way was to ask directly.

My background is mostly with hydromechanical aspects in initial / basic design, but my interests lie with the complete building process, and your company is where I feel they could be put to a good use." Can you see anything inherrently

Comment: wrong with them?

Answer (score 1):

You actually shouldn't try to standardize the tenses here, at least based on what you've provided.  Your first sentance is in the [present progressive](http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarbook/verbs/the-present-progressive-tense/).  You are **currently** writing.

*Wish* is a very odd verb, but the expression is *I wish to -------*, where the blank is an [infinitive](http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarbook/verbs/gerunds-and-infinitives/) verb.  So here, it would be *I wish to join* or *I wish to be (part of)...* .  That being said, *wish* is an unusually formal word choice there.  You'd probably be better off with *I would like to...* (better) or *I want to...* (worse).

Comment: I've been looking for a [link] like that, thank you.